# Should this question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closing

[Fighting Games Terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/what-genre-do-games-like-tekken-and-soulcalibur-belong-to)

I've linked this page because I'm considering re-opening this. It clearly fits within the guidelines attributed in the FAQ.

Consider the following questions as well:
[1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21543/what-genre-of-video-game-does-diablo-belong-to)
[2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/what-attributes-makes-a-game-a-roguelike)
[3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29401/what-is-the-name-of-the-genre-of-games-similar-to-jetpack-joyride)

Is this okay?

Comment: #2 is exactly the sort of question we want; it gives a target, and asks what attributes are required to meet that target.  That's the very definition of good subjective.  The others, not so much, in my opinion.

Comment: IN that case, should 1 and 3 be closed? I'm going to stick with my gut instinct and vote to reopen the fighting games question, but I'd like to get a bit more input from others.

Comment: @fbueckert There's... not really anything subjective about a game genre. This isn't an issue of good vs. bad subjective. It's just looking for the name of the genre, which isn't against site policy.

Comment: @Fluttershy No, my bad.  My wording was crap on that, didn't mean to imply they were bad subjective.  I was trying to point out that if 1 and 3 had been asked as 2 had been, they'd be really GOOD questions.

Comment: @fbueckert That makes more sense. And I completely agree.

Comment: Sidenote: I'm the instigator on closing that question.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6728360#6728360  I still don't think it provides anything of any value whatsoever, and there's no problem to be solved.  But the community can decide how to handle it.

Comment: `identify-that-genre`

Comment: Crap. I meant to push reopen and I pushed delete. Stupid tiny vote buttons on my phone and fat fingers.

Comment: @MatthewRead Is not off topic on this site. If you disagree, write up a meta post about it. Until then, the question should remain open.

Comment: Oh hey, I downvoted all of those. Don't regret any of them one bit, either. Wish I could VTDelete given the low scores.

Comment: @Fluttershy I didn't say anything either way.  Chill out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to agree with you. I can't recall seeing anything in the FAQ, or on Meta, that would indicate that the question is off-topic.

If we're going to close one, we should close the others; or reopen the first one. To that effect, I've voted to reopen the first one.

Do I think it's a *good* question? Absolutely not. But, [a close vote is not a super downvote.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)

Answer (score 4):

**Should this question have been closed as off-topic?**

No, it is clearly within the scope of the site.  Genre/terminology questions are perfectly acceptable according to our FAQ, and I'm not going to vote to re-close it as off-topic.  [Your example #2 is a great question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/what-attributes-makes-a-game-a-roguelike)

**Should this question have been re-opened?**

No.  Just because a question is closed for the wrong reason doesn't always mean it should be re-opened.  Let's be honest here, some questions are just too simple.  That's *not* the same as a legitimate question being easily answered on an easily searchable wiki.  This question practically answers itself.

Lets look at the stats.  As of this writing the question is well over 2 years old, has 1246 views, and has a score of -6.  Now, the age and view count are not condemning in themsleves, but when paired with the score, we have to ask ourselves:  **What did we gain from re-opening this question?**

My answer here is nothing.  Let's look at some similar potential questions:

---

**What genre do games like Gran Turismo and Need for Speed belong to?**

> I mean games where players race cars against each other.

---

**What genre do games like Scribblenauts and Cut the Rope belong to?**

> I mean games where each level is a puzzle which must be solved.

---

Are those questions on topic?  Yep, sure are.  Should I go ask them?  No.  They are of zero use.

So the real question is, why are we rallying to re-open 2 year old garbage? Yes, [a close vote is not a super downvote](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one), but let's just use some common sense. Are we really better off having this question open?  Who is it helping?

So what is to be done?  If we leave it closed as off-topic when it *isn't* off topic, it will give the wrong impression about what is/isn't on-topic.  Since this question is at -6, it should have just been deleted.  Nobody would have missed it and we'd all be better off.

Comment: One potential answer to "who is it helping?" is "Us. Our reputation. Our consistency. Our image." If we're arbitrary and don't follow our own rules as experienced users, especially if we don't fix mistakes later when we find them, then we can't expect the next batch of new users to be any better at using the site well. Having unclosed, high-downvote questions is supposed to happen. Yes, they may have little direct value, but closing them for mysterious reasons not mentioned in any FAQ just gets mud on our trousers. Not walking around in muddy pants has value.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie How is having a question at -8 helping our image.  As clearly I said, the question is not off-topic and should not have been closed as such, but it should have just been deleted because it is practically not even a question.

Comment: Negatives are supposed to happen; they're part of the site design. Note that comments can't be downvoted; there's a reason for that, and a reason that questions can go into the negatives. Closing or deleting any question (that doesn't already match a close/delete criteria) that gets a lot of downvotes is circumventing the system. It helps our image because it says we play by our own rules. It shows that we are not hiding the trash and putting a fake veneer on everything.  It builds trust. Deleting or closing merely bad questions betrays insecurity that users see as tyranny.

Comment: (Aside, "practically not even a question" is literally a close-vote reason, not a delete reason. We must use the right tool for the right job.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Exactly.  Optimally the right tools should be used in the first place, but just because a closable question is closed under the wrong reason doesn't mean it needs to be re-opened.  It just makes it harder for it to be closed for the _right_ reason.  All closed questions (aside from duplicates) should end up being deleted eventually.  Why not just delete the question instead of re-opening, re-closing, then deleting?

Comment: I'm sold. Question deleted; feel free to ask it again.

Comment: I'm fine with it being closed for the right reasons (which ideally would be voted on but in some cases like this has to be judged by a mod), but I'm definitely opposed to the argument that a negative vote score should ever inherently lead to closing/deleting. There will be questions that get lots of downvotes but don't qualify for any of the close or delete criteria, and that's by design.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The score is a symptom.  100% useless questions shouldn't be kept even if they can't quite be closed as off-topic.  I think "100% useless" is (or should be) the criteria for deletion here, not the negative score.  Close votes aren't meant to stand in for downvotes but downvotes can definitely stand in for close votes -- stuff that the community overwhelmingly does not want or like should not be hosted.

Comment: @Matthew That is an invalid generalisation. If the downvotes are a symptom of uselessness, it will get NARQ or NC votes as well. If it doesn't get closed by voting, the downvotes obviously mean something else. Downvotes aren't mini close votes any more than close votes are super downvotes: users who use them like mini close votes either don't have the rep to be trusted with close votes and don't know any better, or they have closing privileges and should know better. Letting downvotes sub for closevotes *en mass* opens the door to abuse of the system.

Comment: I see no conflict with reality there, unpopular questions do get various kinds of votes to close.  If you really think that taking downvotes to mean the community doesn't like something is abusive, you must really dislike that downvotes take rep from the poster, no?