# Can you rescind a close vote?

Tags: discussion, closing

I voted to close [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299795/do-experience-gain-from-damaging-restoration-spells-depend-on-damage-dealt)  before OP edited the question to focus it considerably. While it's still a terrible question, I no longer think it's too broad, and as we know, [close votes aren't super downvotes.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)

Even if you disagree with me, is there a way to rescind a close vote after an edit?

Comment: After a question is closed, nope. All you can do at that point is vote to reopen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cancel a closed vote that you just placed?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/how-do-you-cancel-a-closed-vote-that-you-just-placed)

Answer (score 6):

So long as a question has not yet been closed, yes, you can rescind your close vote.  Simply click the close link again, and the bottom right button is labelled, "Retract Close Vote".  Be aware that doing so will prevent you from voting on it again; you're giving up your ability to close it completely.

Comment: Until it's edited, or never again?

Comment: Never again.  You retract your close vote, that's it, that's all.

Comment: @Dallium If the post is never closed then close votes will eventually expire and can be recast. I would expect retracted close votes can be recast then as well, but I don't know for sure. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting

Comment: Rescinded votes don't get refunded; there's a popup that explicitly tells you that you can't vote to close it again if you rescind it. Aging off is the only way to vote again.

Comment: @RossRidge That is because voting after the first review expires generates a second review, and since you haven't voted on the new review yet, you can still cast (and subsequently retract again) your vote.

Answer (score 3):

As Frank pointed out in his comment you cannot retract close votes after the question has been closed however you can vote to reopen the question if you think it it is on-topic now and has the potential to attract good answers.

Especially when closing as too broad or primarily opinion based, one of the main reasons for closing a question is to get the asker (or someone else in the community) to edit it so it's on-topic again.

Also some "bad" (downvoted) questions have excellent answers so if you think this particular question is a candidate for that go ahead and nominate it for reopening.