# Should 'Account recovery' be marked as off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[How to recover clash of clans account that was not on Google+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/323221/how-to-recover-clash-of-clans-account-that-was-not-on-google)

This question seems to be asked often...

I f-ed up and cant acces my account for x game, how can I recover it.

That question usually has 2 answers

- Contact the devs;
- You are boned.

Its a problem that you cant fix by yourself, so how could we help you more than telling you to contact the devs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those questions are fine if they are not dupes.

An answer containing what account recovery is available for that game and how to use is helpful, relevant and objective. An answer explaining why the account is irretrievably lost is also useful, even if it's not what the asker wants.

If you believe the asker should have done more research to find this answer themselves, go ahead and downvote.

If the question has been asked before, close it as a dupe.

Comment: Guess my gripe with these kind of questions is that they are often low quality by new users.

Comment: @Fredy31 While I agree with you that the majority of these types of questions are often low quality and  from new users, I think the issue here is that there is not enough being done to prevent such questions from getting through. We need to do a better job, somehow, on getting the message across about what it means to submit a higher quality question. I just want to see something that says GOOGLE IT, ya know?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud You can downvote for lack of research. You can make helpful comments about how to submit better questions. However, this does not make the question off-topic. See [a close vote is not a super-downvote. Please don't use it as one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)

Comment: @FoxMcCloud And why do we need to stop these perfectly answerable questions from getting through? To deter new users?

Comment: @Studoku I didn't say anything about stopping new users from asking questions. I said we need to do a better job with giving details of what a high quality question is.