# What happened to this review?

Tags: support, bug, reviewing

I was attempting to [review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/272483) an answer in the VLQ queue. I voted to delete the answer, and a message popped up and said an error occurred, please try again.
I refreshed the page only to be greeted with this.[image: This item is not reviewable]

However, my delete vote was still applied to the answer.

Comment: This is off-topic, but still: Why did you vote to delete? The answer isn't useful, downvote, but it is a valid answer, and should be deleted only if the user posting it wants to. Kinda reminds me of [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one).

Comment: @Quijibo, the answer does not address the question

Comment: Well... there it goes anyways. I've personally never played that game, so if it's as you said, I'm glad you corrected me.

Comment: @Quijibo, to clarify, the question was asking where to find/unlock the recipe, the answer was giving what the recipe was, which is not at all relevant to the question being asked. If it was simply giving the wrong location, I agree, deleting would be wrong, but in this case it wasnt actually addressing the issue in the question, so it is NAA

Comment: My guess is that the binding delete vote by the mod was too quick and the post deleted before you had the chance to complete the review.

Answer (score 4):

For the original error it appears to be a one off error, someone goofed or Tim lost his keys. It appears to be that the error occurred after the delete vote was submitted but before the review was completed so probably as it tried to complete the review. Therefore, when you opened the review again (refreshed the page) as you had already actioned it you couldn't do another action on it again.

You can replicate this behaviour by flagging and/or VTDing outside of queue and then opening the link to the review up. I did this over on SFF where I voted to delete and flagged an answer outside of queue and then opened the review up and it gave the same text as you *"This item is not reviewable."*

---

On a related note here had you skipped or simply closed the review and opened the link up again you should have been able to do the review. (Unless of course you actioned the post outside of review, it completed before you reopened the link or you did the FP or LA on it).