# Is it better to have a lot of similar small questions or one broad question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I once again have to bring up my question on [Pokemon: Ash Grey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122362/what-pokemon-can-be-caught-in-the-different-areas-in-pokemon-ash-grey), and I apologise in advance for my seemingly spamming meta in the last couple of days because of it.

I recently asked which Pokemon could be caught on Route 1, as no official catching guide exists for the game, and I don't want to miss out on "catching them all".

After further research and unable to find a resource online, I decided to test it out myself and post the results. All good.

I then thought to myself that the question/answer were a bit localised, and would be more *useful* if it contained information on the *other areas* - and so I decided to broaden the scope, and continually update my findings, in the hope of creating a resource that future people could use to know which pokemon could be caught throughout the game.

However, It was pointed out to me that the question as it stands currently is probably *too broad*. That's fair enough, and I'm willing to roll back to it's original form if need be, but I'm a bit unsure whether that's the right call.

I'm going to continue testing out the different areas and compile the resource anyway for my own personal use, which I'd like to share with the connumity in one form or another. Which is why I'm wondering, **Do we prefer multiple, similar questions or one large question?**

Comment: [I wrote this answer to a different question, but the standard applies here.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other/3722#3722)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Ah, good stuff, that helps clarify my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the [link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other/3722#3722) posted by LessPop_MoreFizz, in this case:

- There isn't an external source I can point to (otherwise I would),
- The items in the list aren't complicated and don't need their own guides/questions

but I can't deny that

- There's `more than a few elements` in the list.

I will roll back the changes to the original then. Thanks for the clarification.